# Proving finiteness in Reverse Mathematics

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, reverse-math

In (second-order) Reverse Mathematics, a (code for an) open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ is given by two sequences of rationals $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, (b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.  The idea is that $U$ is represented by the union $\cup_n (a_n, b_n)$.  A closed set is the complement of an open set.

Suppose I have a (code for a) closed set $C\subset [0,1]$ which is *finite* as follows:

$$
\text{there is $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any pairwise distinct $x_0, \dots, x_N \in [0,1]$, there is $i\leq N$ with $x_i\not \in C$  }
$$
Clearly, such finite $C$ has measure zero (in the sense of second-order Reverse Mathematics; see X.1 in Simpson's excellent SOSOA).

My question is in what system we can actually prove that such finite $C$ has measure zero?  It would be strange if ATR$_0$ would be needed, for instance.  Any related results from (Turing) computability theory are welcome too.

Comment: One would expect $\mathsf{WWKL}_0$ to be enough, but I'm guessing you might have an issue with not having enough induction to make the 'obvious' proof go through. Do you think something like that is happening?

Comment: Why do you use real intervals in the codes for open sets instead of rationals?

Comment: Presumably you want $x_0, \ldots, x_N$ to be distinct.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Yes $x_0$, ... $x_N$ are distinct.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Because it does not make a difference, I guess.

Comment: @JamesHanson Do provide some more detail: I am both fine with "a proof by induction" and "a proof using WWKL$_0$".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a proof that $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ suffices for the analogous statement over $2^\mathbb{N}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$, where codes for closed sets are viewed as subtrees of $2^{<\mathbb{N}}$; it's a bit tedious, but not difficult, to port this over to $\mathbb{R}$ (the key point being that there is a very-nicely-definable 2-to-1 continuous surjection $2^\mathbb{N}\rightarrow[0,1]$):

Suppose $T$ is a subtree of $2^{<\mathbb{N}}$, coding a closed set $C$ with the desired property. By arithmetic comprehension we can assume $T$ has no dead ends. Now say that a *good sequence* is a finite sequence $\sigma=(x_i)_{i<n}$ such that each $x_i$ is a node on $T$ and if $i<j<n$ then $x_i$ and $x_j$ are incompatible. By the condition on $C$ and the lack of dead ends in $T$, we can uniformly extend each node in $T$ to an element of $C$ ("leftmost extension"), and so we get the analogue of your condition for *nodes* on $T$ rather than *paths*: there is some $N$ such that there is no good sequence of length $\ge N$.

Now consider the set of lengths of good sequences. This is arithmetically definable, so by arithmetic induction and the role of $N$ above it has some largest element. If $\sigma$ is a maximal-length good sequence, then the set of leftmost paths extending elements of $\sigma$ is finite and is all of $C$.

---

On the other hand, $\mathsf{RCA}_0+\mathsf{I}\Sigma^1_1$ also suffices (that is, this finiteness principle has no inherent "effective content"): without even bother to switch to Cantor space, just look at the set of $n$ such that there exists a sequence of distinct elements of $C$ of length $n$. This is a $\Sigma^1_1$ set which is bounded, so it has a greatest element and this gives rise to the finiteness of $C$ as desired.

On the other other hand, it is **not** obvious to me that $\mathsf{RCA}_0+$ arithmetic induction suffices; arithmetic comprehension was crucially used above in pruning $T$.

Comment: I think your continuous surjection from Cantor space needs to be onto $[0,1]$, not $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; induction for $\Sigma_2^1$-formulas seemed sufficient to me, but getting it down to ACA$_0$ is much better.

Comment: @JamesHanson Indeed, fixed!